# Ruby Blather gem, trying to downcase input

Tags: ruby, rubygems, xmpp, chat

I am using Blather to make a chatbot.

I am taking this example from the documentation:

```
message :chat?, :body => 'hello' do |m|
  say m.from, 'world'
end
```

but I would like it to account for ANY 'case' of hello, i.e. hEllo, HELLO, Hello, and respond with world.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a regular expression. In this case, just make a simple case-insensitive match:

```
message :chat?, :body => /hello/i do |m|
  # ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll read [the "guards" documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/blather/file/README.md#Handler_Guards) you'll see:

```
# Hash with regular expression (:body => /exit/)
#   Calls the key on the stanza and checks for a match
#   Equivalent to stanza.body.match /exit/
message :body => /exit/
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at regEx some more.

Comment: Regex are powerful, and also a great way to introduce errors into your logic so go there carefully. `/hello/` will match `"hello"` just as well as it will match `"Phellogen"`, so learn about word boundaries at a minimum.